# Python3 unicode strings with pyobjc

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, pyobjc

I'm converting a lot of python2 scripts that use pyobjc to python3, and having trouble getting them to work. The problem seems to relate to the Unicode changes in python3.

The following call to a pyobjc method works in python2:

```
import Quartz as Quartz
filename = '/path/to/myfile.pdf'
provider = Quartz.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(filename)
```

but in python 3, I get `ValueError: depythonifying 'char', got 'str' of 1`

This can be fixed by encoding the string first:

```
filenameNonU = filename.encode('utf-8')
provider = Quartz.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(filenameNonU)
```

... and the script works, ***unless*** the string includes 'non-ASCII' characters (e.g. `Ä∂∫ß`), in which case, I get:  `ValueError: depythonifying 'char', got 'int' of wrong magnitude`

Using the codec `'raw-unicode-escape'` works for ASCII range; and does **not** flag an error for strings with Unicode chars, but just returns `None` from the method, so it seems like it's just a question of getting the right codec.

So, my question is: what do I need to do to get my strings in the same format as python2 was using, so that the pyobjc method will deal with them correctly?

python2 returns something like:

```
A\xcc\x88\xc6\x92\xe2\x88\x82
```

for Unicode characters higher than 128; and I get the same result in python3 when encoded utf-8, except for the b prefix.

raw_unicode_escape gives something like `A\\u0308\\u0192\\u2202`, which is a different format.

It's no coincidence that the methods with this problem use pointers as their arguments in ObjC. But one of the benefits of python is that it (up to now) handles things like types and pointers invisibly.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ Apart from loading the library and having a variable, that's it.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the default codec for implicit `str`/`unicode` conversion in Python 2 was Latin-1. (The `# coding: utf-8` comment only affects interpretation of string literals and doesn't override other encoding defaults.)

Comment: @lenz Thanks, but Latin-1 gives "codec can't encode characters in position 39-41: ordinal not in range(256)".

Comment: `'A\xcc\x88\xc6\x92\xe2\x88\x82'.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'Äƒ∂'`…

Comment: @JosefZ Yes, that was sample text. But thanks for the codec. See my additional bit in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got in touch with Ronald Oussoren, the maintainer of pyObjC, and he's confirmed there's a bug causing the problem with characters above 255.

This has now been fixed in pyobjc 8.5.

For the avoidance of doubt, the correct encoding for strings passed as arguments should be `utf8`.